# C# SQL stored procedure output to array or list from Try block

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, list, datagridview

I have a method in which Sql stored procedure is executed taking values from Datagridview cells.This part of code is in Try Catch block.

What I need is to get all SP output values and other information from Datagridview cells to array or list, and after all rows have been processed to create a datatable and to use it as datasource for another Datagridview.

Can you please suggest how I can take values from Try block? And which one is recommended to use in this situation: list or array?

Comment: 1. Create a `List` before the try block.  2. Add items to the list within the try block.  Use a `List` if the number of items is not known, as an array has a fixed size.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like stored procedures are often highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

You might simply return the result object from inside the try-block. It's totally valid to have a return-command inside a try catch.
List or Array depends on whether you know the amount of elements before creating the list or array. Since you don't need the result list outside the method (and so you can assume that nobody else needs to add elements to it) using an array might save you a fraction of a second in processing time - but the list implementation of .net uses an array behind the scenes, so when you can call the constructor with a parameter of type int for the expected amount of elements, the overhead of a lisst is far less than calling the SP - so you can simply use the type you like.